# m1mac から ubuntu22.04にssh接続できない

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

macbookからリモートサーバにアクセスしたいのですが、接続ができずに困っています。少しでもアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。以下に詳細を記載いたします。

**環境**
リモート先: ubuntu22.04, mac　mini2014(Late)
クライアント:　macbook air (M1, 2020)

**エラー内容**
パスワードを3回入力後に以下のようなエラーが出ます。macの公開鍵もリモートサーバに登録できており、パスワードも間違っていないと思います。

```
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

**やったこと**

1. ssh -vvv を実行して、以下が出力されました。

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg932\cocoartf2759
\cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgray\c0;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww11520\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs22 \cf2 \CocoaLigature0 OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6\
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files\
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *\
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts'\
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts2'\
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling\
debug1: Connecting to pcname.local port 22.\
debug1: Connection established.\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\
debug1: identity file /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.4\
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6\
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK\
debug1: Authenticating to pcname.local:22 as 'remote_pcname'\
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1\
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from pcname.local\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory\
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim\
debug3: send packet: type 20\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\
debug3: receive packet: type 20\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c\
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256\
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\
debug2: languages ctos: \
debug2: languages stoc: \
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 \
debug2: reserved 0 \
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com\
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\
debug2: languages ctos: \
debug2: languages stoc: \
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 \
debug2: reserved 0 \
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com\
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519\
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none\
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none\
debug3: send packet: type 30\
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\
debug3: receive packet: type 31\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received\
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ADYaCMhToe/2nzHAVT+hznUNAjFMpzkybLpwyl+gLAU\
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1\
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from pcname.local\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory\
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory\
debug1: Host 'pcname.local' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.\
debug1: Found key in /Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1\
debug3: send packet: type 21\
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1\
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\
debug3: receive packet: type 21\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0\
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks\
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ECq6QYghw6/Listeners'\
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey\
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities\
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256 : -------
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa \
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk \
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 \
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk \
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss \
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa \
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done\
debug3: send packet: type 5\
debug3: receive packet: type 7\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>\
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>\
debug3: receive packet: type 6\
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\
debug3: send packet: type 50\
debug3: receive packet: type 51\
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password\
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password\
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password\
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey\
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256 : -------
debug3: send packet: type 50\
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\
debug3: receive packet: type 51\
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory\
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa\
debug3: no such identity: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\
debug3: authmethod_lookup password\
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password\
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password\
debug1: Next authentication method: password\
remote_pcname@pcname.local's password: \
debug3: send packet: type 50\
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\
debug3: receive packet: type 51\
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\
Permission denied, please try again.\
remote_pcname@pcname.local's password: \
debug3: send packet: type 50\
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\
debug3: receive packet: type 51\
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\
Permission denied, please try again.\
remote_pcname@pcname.local's password: \
debug3: send packet: type 50\
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\
debug3: receive packet: type 51\
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password\
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.\
remote_pcname@pcname.local: Permission denied (publickey,password).}
```

以上になります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ログメッセージに `Offering public key: /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:` があって、`debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply` となって、結果は `receive packet: type 51` です。つまり、公開鍵認証に失敗していることが判ります。SSH の接続時ログだけでは、これ以上の事は分かりません。`SSH publickey receive packet: type 51` で検索すれば調査方法などがヒットするかと思います。

Comment: Ubuntu側の /var/log/auth.log の該当時刻のログを確認するといいと思います

Comment: アドバイスいただきありがとうございます。`cat /var/log/auth.log` でログを確認したところ、mac側のアカウント名でアクセスしているようで、mac でのアカウント名と同様のアカウントをubuntuに作ったところ問題なく接続できました。しかしながら、できればubuntu側の違うユーザ名のアカウントにssh接続したいのですが、何か方法がございませんでしょうか。`ssh PCname.local`で接続しております。

Answer (score 1):

みなさまアドバイスありがとうございました。無事に解決しました。
macではssh接続時にユーザ名を指定してあげる必要がありました。

```
ssh user_name@PCname.local
```

Answer (score 1):

すでに解決済みのようですが、もう少しだけ補足となるような説明を別解として。

接続元と接続先とでユーザーが異なる場合、どのユーザーでログインするのかを明示的に指定しないといけません。指定が無いと接続元と同じユーザーでのログインを試みます。(接続先に該当ユーザーが存在しなければ当然ログインには失敗する)

ログインユーザーの指定は `-l` オプション、もしくは接続先ホストと一緒に `@` の前に指定します。

- `ssh -l user hostname`
- `ssh user@hostname`